# Extracting from json multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array and trying to extract an object with an if statement that if a key equals a specific value then get that corresponding object. So what I'm trying to do is build an if statement that says, if "LABEL" equals "TitleOne" then output the ID and ADDRESS1

My json:

```
var data = [
    [
        {
            "LABEL": "TitleOne"
        },
        {
            "ID": "204",                        
            "Address1": "123 main st",
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "LABEL": "TitleTwo"
        },
        {
            "Total": "17490"
            "DaysDisplay": "5.0 days"
        }
    
]
];
```

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
if(data[0].LABEL == 'TitleOne'){
console.log(data.[0].ID);
}
```

Comment: How are you fetching through the array?

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm getting the array with C#/Asp Net Core 6 but outputting in through jQuery

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm using ASP.NET Core json serialize i.e var data= @Json.Serialize(model);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to find the child arrays in your outer array which have the specified `LABEL`. From there you can access the `ID` and `Address1` property values.

Note that the below code assumes only 1 `LABEL` match per set. If you have more than one match you would need to loop through to retrieve the properties from each child array instead of accessing the 0th element.

```js
const data = [
  [{ "LABEL": "TitleOne" }, { "ID": "204", "Address1": "123 main st" }],
  [{ "LABEL": "TitleTwo" }, { "Total": "17490", "DaysDisplay": "5.0 days" }]
];

let targetItem = data.filter(x => x[0].LABEL == 'TitleOne');
console.log(targetItem[0][1].ID)
console.log(targetItem[0][1].Address1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the exact output I was looking for. I've actually never used the filter function but now I know